# Submitting webapp launcher to Apple Store

Tags: ios, app-store

I have never developed for iPhone, but I have developed an HTML5 web application.

I would like to submit to the Apple store a free app whose job would be to just open up the HTML5 webapp in the mobile browser.

Do you think it will be likely that such an app can be accepted? Can you please provide links or evidence?

Is it possible to ask this question to the Apple team so that I am not going to waste $99? If so, how?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think there are already many webapps published via the app store. If you can also use an alternative, give openappmkt.com a try. It's a cool site for publishing your html webapps.

Comment: I don't know if this is possible or not, but I'm not sure you really need to do this. Users can create what are effectively shortcuts to a particular webpage straight from Safari. They look and behave like apps on the home screen, but they just open up the browser and zoom straight to your page.

Comment: Hi Cody. I know that is possible but I am noticing how my users don't understand this whole concept yet - they just go to the Apple store, they don't find my app thus they assume they can't run my product on their iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

If your app has native web views pulling internal HTML5 information, you might be able to sneak it by some of the app reviewers, but a good portion will say that there is not enough native Apple code in the app. They are sticklers for that.

I have, on a few occasions, gotten away with adding push notification, saying it HAS to be an app, and can't rely on users going to the website since they need push (even though I never intended on pushing anything out), but Apple has caught on to this.

Ultimately, you need to use Apple code in xCode, and you need to use a lot of it.